# PHP echo display - Missing first Row from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I'm not sure why it is happening. I have read some explanations on here but can't seem to find it myself.

On both my series and episodes lists for my site I am missing the first row when echoing the results. Any help to fix this would be great.

Here's the coding for the episode page

```
<?php include '../connect/dbseries.php' ?>


<?php   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT 
                            seriesID, 
                            seasonindex, 
                            sortname, 
                            thumbfilename,
                            CurrentBannerFilename,
                            PosterBannerFileName, 
                            summary, 
                            IMDB_ID,
                            episodename,
                            episodeindex,
                            compositeid

                            FROM Series

                            WHERE seriesid = '$_GET[id]'

                            order by Seasonindex, Episodeindex ASC;");
if (!$result2) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
//setup array
$ID = $row2['0'];
$seasonindex = $row2['1'];
$Sortname = $row2['2'];
$thumb = $row2['3'];
$Bannerfilenames = $row2['4'];
$currentbanner = $row2['5'];
$Summary = $row2['6'];
$imdb = $row2['7'];
$EN = $row2['9'];
$Eid = $row2['9'];
$cid = $row2['10'];

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
echo  '<br /> <a href="seriesinfo.php?id='.$row['compositeid'].'"><img src="../images/series/'.$row['thumbfilename'].'" width="200" height="200"></a> "'.$row['summary'].'" "'. $row['episodename'] .'" "'. $row['episodeindex'] .'"' ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing because of:
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);

mysql_fetch_row moves the internal data pointer ahead that's why you are echoing the second record. try echoing before while and your problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching the first row, setting your variables, then fetching row 2.... modify your while

```
do {
    echo  '<br /> <a href="seriesinfo.php?id='.$row['compositeid'].'"><img src="../images/series/'.$row['thumbfilename'].'" width="200" height="200"></a> "'.$row['summary'].'" "'. $row['episodename'] .'" "'. $row['episodeindex'] .'"' ;
} while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2));
```

or delete the line of code that does the initial fetch, and all your redundant variable assignments from $row2

Comment: thank you this has worked a treat. now got one last error to fix but thats a video isse ./sigh